# Hot Wire Cutter stops working after certain length

Tags: power-supply

I'm making a super basic hot wire foam cutter, using NiCr 80 as the resistor. It stops working once my cutter wire exceeds a length that, based on what I'm calculating, should be well within the paramaters of functionality.

The calculations I did by hand matched what I found on this calculator here: https://jacobs-online.biz/calc2.html (keep in mind they use a slightly different number for ohms but its close enough, as far as I can tell)

My target temp is at least 600deg (above that is fine, I'm not picky here). I'm using [this 12v 5a output power supply](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GEA8PQA), [this 20 gauge nicr80](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CHTY1VV), [these temp tables](https://wiretron.com/nichrome-resistance-informational-charts/) and [these resistance tables](https://resistancewire.com/uploads/page/ADT2001_12_17_N8_ENG.pdf). I'm using 20 gauge AWG stranded wire for the connections.

Following are calculations I did for three resistor wire lengths of 12, 18, and 24 inches.

```
Constants:
R = .6363 per ft (base resistance multiplier)
I = 5.1 for 600 deg target temperature in 20 gauge NiCr80
V = 12v constant from my supply

1 ft (R = .6363):
V = I * R
V = 5.1 * .6363
**V = 3.24513**

1.5 ft (R = 0.95445):
V = I * R
V = 5.1 * .95445
**V = 4.867695**

2 ft (R = 1.2726):
V = I * R
V = 5.1 * 1.2726
**V = 6.49026**
```

I tested it quickly using 12in, 15in, and 19in wires.

12 inches works fine.
15 inches works fine.
**19 inches produces zero temperature difference that I can discern.**

My maximum length calculation to reach the temperature required:

```
x ft:
12 = 5.1 * R
R = 2.3529
Length = 2.3529 / .6363
**L = 3.6977 feet** or roughly 40 inches.
```

I guess what I'm getting at is, this power supply should theoretically support up to 40 inches of 20 gauge NiCr wire and actually is overkill for these shorter lengths (like, dangerously so).

I am missing something that I clearly don't understand around how power supplies deliver power? If my voltage is a constant 12v, theoretically the amperage for those lower-resistance sitations should go through the roof. At that point, I think one of two things should happen:

1. OC protection should come on and the power supply should simply not deliver any current?
2. It delivers a maximum of 5a as its rated for. Current supplied would be exactly what is required.

The head scratcher for me is, if OC is kicking on, it should do so for all of these lenghts since the voltage is much higher than I need for *any* of these lengths, right?

I have tested this with multiple wires and am getting consistent failure at the longer lengths. Am I miscalculating, or misunderstanding something?

Additional notes:

- I get consistent 12v voltmeter readings no matter what length of wire I use.
- I get 0 amps when putting the meter inline after the resistor wire in the circuit. Likely this is my problem...

Thanks

Comment: @dudewad - You've *measured* the supply in operation, or are simply quoting its specs? We can't tell and option 0 can't be assumed.

Comment: Any load with resistance less than 2.4 ohms will overload the supply and it won't work properly - it is said to have overcurrent protection so it may just start and shut down constantly and that is just enough to heat up the wire, and longer wire just won't heat at all. So it is unlikely that the supply outputs constant 12V, or there is some other problem which is not indicated by these calculations.

Comment: You are trying to pull 5.1 Amps from a 5 Amp supply. A cheap no name supply from China. That alone is a problem. You are also trying to push only 3V from a 12V constant voltage supply without using a regulator which doesn't work.

Comment: @Justme ok that explanation makes a lot more sense. I was wondering why it would heat up with LESS resistance given that current should shoot through the roof as far as I can tell.
I'll try this experiment with a smaller gauge wire and make sure to keep things within parameters of the supply. Thanks.

Comment: @jsotola I did measure it under a load and am consistenly getting 12v, yes.

Comment: @jsotola I updated it. I also note that I'm not getting any current readings under any circumstances. I'm putting the meter inline after the resistor. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong there.

Comment: With what you are measuring current and how? If you have a break, bad connection, or blew the multimeter fuse with overcurrent, no current will flow, and voltage will be 12V at 0A load.

Comment: I'm going to check the fuse. I imagine that my ignorant self blew the fuse. I just thought since I was getting a voltage reading that wasn't the case. Will check it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on theoretical numbers here. You need actual measurements. Grab a multimeter or two. Measure the voltage of the supply, measure the voltage of the wire when you power it, measure the actual resistance of the wires, and measure the current.

You will likely find the supply is not happy and has turned itself off at those higher current needs. That it doesn't shut down when you place a 1/2 ohm load across the 12V supply which should be pulling 15+ amps means that it is very unreliable.

Also you should never even ***try*** to pull 5.1 Amps from a 5 Amp supply. Frankly the good rule of thumb is that supplies should only be used at 80 or 90 percent of the rated capacity most of the time.

The problem here is that you aren't considering that this is a constant voltage supply. It should be trying to push 12V regardless of your load resistance.  It will/ should not drop down its voltage to meet your theoretical goals.

You put a 0.6 ohm load on a 12v supply it should be trying to provide 20 Amps. At 1.2 ohms it should be trying to provide 10 Amps.

Comment: I did measure voltage and am consistenly getting 12v no matter how long the resistor wire is.

Comment: And the current? Measure that too. @dudewad

Comment: I also did that, I don't get a current measurement for any of my lengths. I'm putting the meter inline after the resistor wire. Should I be doing it differently?

Comment: @dudewad did you blow the fuse? Some common meters are limited to 10 Amps. Here you may be pulling almost 20 Amps.

Comment: That had occurred to me but I thought that because I was getting readings for voltage that I hadn't. I'll check it and see.

Comment: The voltage section of your multimeter doesn't go through the current section. Typically @dudewad

Comment: Learning new stuff every day 